# Better performance of pattern matching over foldr

Tags: performance, haskell, pattern-matching, fold

Both of these functions are implementations of a dictionary lookup picked out from [learnyouahaskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/modules)

```
findKeyPatMatch :: (Eq k) => k -> [(k,v)] -> Maybe v
findKeyPatMatch key [] = Nothing
findKeyPatMatch key ((k,v):xs)
    | key == k      = Just v
    | otherwise     = findKeyPatMatch key xs

findKeyFold :: (Eq k) => k -> [(k,v)] -> Maybe v
findKeyFold key = foldr (\(k,v) acc -> if k == key then Just v else acc) Nothing
```

Since the pattern in the first function is the exact idiom foldr is made for, I expected both of these functions to have the same performance. However, the pattern matching implementation is significantly faster.
`foldr` short-circuits, so I can't think of any particular reason for this, except for *maybe* a function call overhead, at a stretch.

```
testKey = 10^7
testDict = [(i,i) | i <- [1..]]

findKeyPatMatch testKey testDict    -- takes ~3.40 s
findKeyFold testKey testDict        -- takes ~4.10 s
```

So my question is - what's the reason for the performance difference, and is there any way to optimize the foldr expression.

Comment: How are you running these? Compiler otimizations will make a big difference. Results from ghci would not be accurate.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/haskell/info

Comment: I can't reproduce. I get an average of 87ms vs 82ms with Criterion and compiling with -O2. The difference is very small.

Comment: @Rein Heinrichs
Ah okay. This was timed with ghci.

Comment: I reproduce the difference with compiled code (-O2) with GHC 7.10.3: ~130ms for `findKeyPatMatch` vs ~230ms for `findKeyFold`.  The numbers are pretty consistent across runs, varying only in the 3-rd digit.

Comment: After some tinkering with the test bed, the difference is lost, somehow (could have been a mistake in my initial setup, though I'm not sure how exactly copy & paste could have gone wrong.)  Now I'm getting ~90ms for both cases.